# How do industrial robots solve the inverse kinematic problem?

Tags: robotic-arm, inverse-kinematics, matlab, simulation, industrial-robot

I want to make a real-time end-effector position control simulation of a 6 DOF robotic arm. To do so, I should solve the inverse kinematic problem, but due to the complexity of calculations, it is impossible to do that in real-time. As I know, industrial robots like KUKA or ABB can solve the inverse kinematic problem in real-time. Can anyone help me with the algorithms and explain those solutions to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closed-form inverse kinematic equations are used to determine joint angles based on the end effector pose.  These equations are well established in the literature.  For example, the classic robotics books by Craig or by Paul show the equations for typical 6dof industrial arms.

Comment: By the way, with regard to the “not possible to do in real time” part of your question:  I programmed 6dof articulated arm inverse kinematics on an 80386 processor in the early 1990s, and closed the loop at over 100Hz.  Today’s microprocessors can achieve near real-time loop rates much higher than that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You suggest to use an analytical solution to solve the inverse kindmatic problem. what about the numerical solution? Why indutrial robots do not use a look up table and pre determined values for the inverse kindmatic? Because I think that would be faster.

Comment: I don’t why you would use a numerical solution when there are exact equations available.

Comment: It depends how accurate you want to be. An alytical solutions are mainly fasters and for a complex structure It is highly recommended to use analytical solution

Comment: The lookup-tables for compensation values are combined with the analytical inverse kinematics solution. You have a large lookup table to increase the precision of the analytical solution

Comment: I agree with you and what Steve mentioned earlier but I  think generally the analytical solution is more precise compared to numerical solutions. In my opinion, the best way that I can use in the simulation is to create a look-up table and then train a neural network based on the data. I that case It would be more exact compared to a look-up table and the calculations can be done with less delay. of course the accuracy is less than an analytical solution.

Comment: One other thing you may consider is that analytical solutions are accurate for the ideal kinematic model of the robot.  Nothing is ever constructed to 100% meet the ideal parameters.  So industrial robots often use a calibration algorithm to correct for the slight inaccuracies in link lengths and motor axis alignments.   This is similar to the comment by @50k4 about using a lookup table after solving for the analytical solution, although the calibration might also just modify the kinematic parameters of the model.

Comment: The analytical solution is fast, but it is not more precise, as @SteveO mentioned, real robots are not ideal. Numerical solution can be fast enough (<2ms) to increase precision, if they get a good initial guess. A good initial guess is the analytical solution. Further compensation lookup tables (or NN, or any other models, functions or function approximations ) can be added on top, usually for effects which are not modelled. Reasobly sized NNs are fast (<2ms), iff they are calculated on a GPU/TPU, Getting a real-time OS AND a real-time GPU/TPU access is far from trivial! that

Answer (score 0):

3 motors from the base decide the xyz position of the end effector and the other 3 on the tip decide the rotation of it. This is a really simple model as Steve mentioned. I don't know how much speed do you need but it will easily reach 10kHz and over to numerically solve the inverse kinematics with a modern computer and modern lib such as ceres.